# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require - JQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I use this code in my .js file which is part of web site that is used via npm global http-server:

```
function getParsedStorage() {
  let fs = require('fs');
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./../manager-data.json', 'utf8'));
}
```

and get errors:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Can't find variable: require (2) (exceptionHook — jquery.min.js:2:31584)
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require (jquery.min.js:2:31697)

I've installed file-system package with *npm install file-system --save* but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're attempting to make use of Node.js's [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) function from within a web browser without using a module system that provides a compatible `require` method.

Without additional information I can't be certain, however my advice would be to investigate a module loader like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/), [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) which should all enable you to make use of this syntax in your module.

That being said, for the use case you're describing (accessing a JSON file from a website) you may be better served using a simple [XHRHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

The following is an example which makes use of the `fetch` API to return the parsed JSON file content.

```
// Returns a Promise that resolves to the parsed storage data
// NOTE: Lacks any error handling
function getParsedStorage() {
  return fetch("../manager-data.json").then(response => response.json())
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was a moment of coding madness and despair. Thank you for your answer. Now I've learned a little about node.js and do my server part using it.